# Java file get content to first empty line

Tags: java, file, split

I need to split the first section of a file in Java, before the first empty line and the second section, after this line. How can I do this? Currently, I read the files with this code:

```
try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        return scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "500 - Server Error";
    }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: My idea is a while loop

Comment: What about using a BufferedReader and use readLine(). You save all lines in a Collection until readLine returns an empty line. Now you save everything that follows in another Collection

Comment: I wonder if this helps: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly,see following code:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("d:\\tmp\\zyr.txt"));
    String delimiter = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    scanner.useDelimiter(delimiter);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(!(line.trim().length()==0)){
            sb.append(line).append(delimiter);
        }else if(sb.toString().length()>0) {
            result.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    if(sb.toString().length()>0) {
        result.add(sb.toString());
    }


    System.out.println("first section:");
    System.out.println(result.get(0));
    System.out.println("second section:");
    System.out.println(result.get(1));
```

the `zyr.txt` file is like:

```
abc
abc
abc

123
123
```

and the the first section which you want is first item in `result` list,the second is the second item.

the print result is:

```
first section:
abc
abc
abc

second section:
123
123
```

Comment: The first section of this file is a conig section. How can I split the lines by ":" ?

Comment: @Markus Please post your first section.

Comment: It's someting like 
`Content-type: text/plain`

Comment: @Markus you can use method `split`,will return a array,the first item in array  is `Content-type`,the other is `text/plain`

Comment: I know. But how can I split the lines from the first block?

Comment: New Problem. After a second word wrap `result.get(1)` does not contains the content after it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach: read the whole file, then split by "\n\n" into two parts:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class SplitFileByBlankLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String blankLine = System.getProperty("line.separator") + "{2}";

        // Read the whole contents, assuming small to moderate size
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data.txt")));

        // Split the contents by blank line into two parts
        String[] partition = contents.split(blankLine, 2);

        // Print out for visual verification
        System.out.println(partition[0]); // Text before the blank line
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println(partition[1]); // Text after
    }
}
```

It seems you are trying to parse the http response. I am new to Java, but I think there must be a library somewhere to do the task.